# how does this for loop work in C# for (; (p %= l) != 0; l -= p, index += p)

Tags: c#

I found this for loop in one of the solutions for Rotating array problem. I am not able to understand this line in the code.

```
    public void RotateArray(int[] nums, int p)
    {
        var l = nums.Length;
        var index = 0;
        for (; (p %= l) != 0; l -= p, index += p)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
            {
                var temp = nums[l - p + i + index];
                nums[l - p + i + index] = nums[i + index];
                nums[i + index] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

this solution is working but not able to get the meaning of the condition in this for loop.

Comment: Bleughh who wrote that, were they playing code-golf at the time?

Comment: That's the sort of code that hard-core C/C++ developers will write where the point is to type as few characters as possible and readability be damned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a `for` loop is confusing, it's sometimes helpful to replace it with a `while` loop, because it has a more ordered depiction of the code execution order, i.e. you can read the code "from top to bottom" rather than having to jump around.

A `for` loop with a code of

```
code before loop;
for (initialization; condition; modifications) {
  loop body;
}
code after loop;
```

can be translated into this `while`:

```
code before loop;
initialization;
while (condition) {
  loop body;
  modifications;
}
code after loop;
```

Now let's modify your given code:

```
public void RotateArray(int[] nums, int p)
{
    var l = nums.Length;
    var index = 0;
    while ((p %= l) != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            var temp = nums[l - p + i + index];
            nums[l - p + i + index] = nums[i + index];
            nums[i + index] = temp;
        }
        l -= p;
        index += p;
    }
}
```

We can make it even easier on ourselves by changing a few more things:

- replacing the abbreviated variables `p` and `l` with `places` and `length`
- renamed `index` to `offset` (you will see why)
- extracting the assignment from the `while` loop condition
- Create variables `a` and `b` for the swap indices
- Use [tuple assignment and decomposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-assignment-and-deconstruction) to [swap the array contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0180#example)
- rewriting the compound assignments as normal assignments (this one is personal taste; I'd usually keep them in my code, but sometimes writing them explicitly helps, and when reading complicated code, every little bit might help)

All this is done to reduce the number of things we have to keep mental track of:

```
public void RotateArray(int[] nums, int places)
{
    var length = nums.Length;
    var offset = 0;
    places = places % length;

    while (places != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < places; i++)
        {
            var a = i + offset;
            var b = length - places + i + offset;
            (nums[a], nums[b]) = (nums[b], nums[a]);
        }

        length = length - places;
        offset = offset + places;
        places = places % length;
    }
}
```

To understand what this does, it's best to look at an example:

[image: Example of rotating a length-7 array by 5 places]

What we can see is that after each outer loop, a part of the array has been successfully rotated. This is what `offset` (or originally `index`) keeps track of. `length` (or `l`) keeps track of the length of the "rest" that needs a few rotations still.

We can also see that the modulus operator `%` is there to make sure that we keep the indices down within the array. It's clear that rotating a length-7 array by 4 would be the same as rotating it by 11, 18, 25, etc., or generally speaking, rotating an array of length `n` by `(c * n) + x` places is the same as rotating by just `x` places, which is what the modulus is for.

And lastly we see that `offset`/`index` is basically just use to shift all activities into the region we are working on.

The "difficult" part in understanding lies in proving that after each inner loop, the left "done" part has increased, and understanding *why* you can calculate the next `places`/`p` like this. But mathematically proving this algorithm goes beyond the scope of this post.

In general I recommend to create such visualizations as I did, which keep track of variable values and the manipulations. Do it for different values of `length` and `places` (e.g. 7/5) to get an even better understanding.

As others have pointed out, this code is very C#-unlike, where the order in which we value property of code is in general "clarity > brevity > performance" with exceptions only being made where warranted by the application.

Comment: Note this is exactly what ILSpy (https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) will show when used on this function.

Answer (score 2):

To understand *your* actual code from the question, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78039136/1843468).

**This** answer is meant to guide you towards an implementation that is much more like what C# code would usually look like:

### Improvement 1: Using LINQ and Array.Copy

While there is no need to use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/linq/) for collection manipulation, it can greatly reduce the amount of code you need to write. The named functions [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) and [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) also help with understanding what the code does. Since LINQ will create a new array, you have to use [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.copy) to modify the content of the parameter in-place.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public void RotateArray(int[] nums, int places)
{
    var length = nums.Length;
    places %= length;
    var rotated = nums.Skip(length - places).Concat(nums.Take(length - places)).ToArray();
    Array.Copy(rotated, nums, length);
}
```

### Improvement 2: Make the function pure

Over the years, C# has developed a tendency away from in-place modification to "pure" functions, at least for these functions on basic types such as an array. Pure functions do not alter the state of the object or the parameters. This is also called "having no side effects" and essentially means it can be called multiple times on the same object with the same arguments, and will always return the same result. Very well-known examples are `string` functions such as [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) or [`PadLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft).

Marking the method with the [`[Pure]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute) makes sure an editor or IDE with code analysis will show [a warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1806) for usages of the function where the return value is not used (try `"1".PadLeft(3, '0');` without assigning the result to a variable).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

[Pure]
public int[] RotateArray(int[] nums, int places)
{
    var length = nums.Length;
    places %= length;
    return nums.Skip(length - places).Concat(nums.Take(length - places)).ToArray();
}
```

### Improvement 3: A generic extension

In an even better version, you write this code using [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics). This means you can now use this function not only to rotate an array of `int`, but an array of any type.

Creating the function as an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) means you can simply type `nums.Rotate(5);` instead of `RotateArray(nums, 5)`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    [Pure]
    public static T[] Rotate<T>(this T[] source, int places)
    {
        var length = source.Length;
        places %= length;
        return source.Skip(length - places).Concat(source.Take(length - places)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

### Improvement 4: Input validation and shifting backwards

You should also validate the parameters, e.g. checking for `null` and throwing an [`ArgumentNullException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception). We can also add the [`[NotNull]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute) to help the [static null-state analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) know what variables can be null where in the code.

And while we're at it, we can deal with negative values of `places` by calling [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.throwifnegative), or we can rather elegantly use negative values to allow shifting in the opposite direction.

Note how we also added a shortcut for when we don't need to rotate anything. We still create a new array using the [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) method to make sure the return value is *always* a new array, and not unexpectedly the input one but only in these special cases.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    [Pure]
    [return: NotNull]
    public static T[] Rotate<T>([NotNull] this T[] source, int places)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        // ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative(places);
        
        var length = source.Length;
        if (length == 0) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot rotate empty array.");
        }
        places %= length;
        if (places == 0) {
            return source.ToArray();
        } else if (places < 0) {
            places += length;
        }
        return source.Skip(length - places).Concat(source.Take(length - places)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

### Optional: Use ranges

And finally, if you want to make it even a bit shorter yet, you can use the [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.range) feature instead of LINQ's `Skip` and `Take`. It's likely personal preference what is considered easier to read and understand.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    [Pure]
    [return: NotNull]
    public static T[] Rotate<T>([NotNull] this T[] source, int places)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        // ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative(places);
        
        var length = source.Length;
        if (length == 0) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot rotate empty array.");
        }
        places %= length;
        if (places == 0) {
            return source.ToArray();
        } else if (places < 0) {
            places += length;
        }
        var wrap = length - places;
        return source[wrap..].Concat(source[..wrap]).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a new array of the exact size and using `Array.Copy` or `Span.Copy` might be faster.

Comment: Faster than `ToArray()` in the `places == 0` branch? Firstly, as I mentioned in the other answer, I am quite confident most people prefer easier code over faster code for cases like these. Secondly, I would argue `Enumerable.ToArray` does [precisely](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs#L30) [that](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.CoreCLR.cs#L723).

Comment: True it does if it's an `ICollection`, but you are using Skip/Take which are not `ICollection`, or ranges which force another copy.

Comment: So you are talking about he final return line, not the `places == 0` branch, I see. Yes, creating the new array and using Array.Copy twice could be faster there.

Answer (score 0):

Unravelling the syntactic sugar of that `for` loop. Trying to keep the rest of the code the same, but making it more readable by renaming variables;

```cs
public void RotateArray(int[] nums, int steps)
{
    var length = nums.Length;
    var start = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        steps = steps % length;
        if (steps == 0)
            break;

        var dest = start + length - steps;

        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            var temp = nums[dest + i];
            nums[dest + i] = nums[start + i];
            nums[start + i] = temp;
        }

        length -= steps;
        start += steps;
    }
}
```

On each iteration of the loop, the first `steps` items in the array are swapped with the last `steps` items. Then we advance by `steps` and do it again.

If these two ranges don't overlap. Then you can consider that the last `steps` elements of the array are used as temporary space to shuffle each chunk of the array forwards.

Once these two ranges overlap, the result is a bit messy. eg for `RotateArray({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, 7)` the first loop would end up with `{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,0}`. The last `steps` items were moved to the start, the first `dest - start` items were moved to the end. But the order of these items was also rotated since the elements were swapped a different number of times. Since `(dest - start) % steps != 0`.

But we're not done yet. We'll keep shuffling the remainder of the array until those last items have been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

That is extremely unreadable code, borderline obfuscated. Using a While loop will make it *easier* to understand, all it's doing is swapping the items in the array by shuffling *them with a rotation the number of steps*:

```
public void RotateArray(int[] array, int steps)
{
    int length = array.Length;
    steps %= length;

    if (steps == 0)
        return; // No need to rotate if steps is 0

    Shuffle(array, 0, length - 1);
    Shuffle(array, 0, steps - 1);
    Shuffle(array, steps, length - 1);
}

public void Shuffle(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
    while (start < end)
    {
        int temp = array[start];
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

I'd recommend doing it with LINQ:

```
public int[] RotateArray(int[] array, int steps)
{
    steps %= array.Length;
    return array.Skip(steps).Concat(array.Take(steps)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Nice, but how does that answer OP’s question? So, how does that help OP understand the original code.

Comment: This is a failed translation, the iterator section should be executed in the end of the loop. You will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you run `RotateArray(new int[]{1,2,3}, 2);`

Comment: @shingo good pick up. Fixed up.

Comment: Re-assigning the `array` variable within this `void` function is not really going to do much for the array you passed in. You either need a `ref` param, or must `return` the new array (and probably mark the method `[Pure]` so the compiler will warn the user if they forget to use the return value). Or you can create a new variable and use `Array.CopyTo` to modify the content of the original `array`.

Comment: Oh I mean `Array.Copy`. `CopyTo` is from `Stream`.